# Can I use a GPL licensed piece of JavaScript on a commercial website?

Tags: licensing

I'm looking at plupload for some upload features on a website I'm developing. Now plupload is GNU GPLv2 licensed and that implies that all derivative software should also be GPL licensed (right?). Therefore I run the plupload through my minifier, the single minified js file will violate the license, and upon request, I must make *all* the sources of my page available (right?).

I'm curious about:

- can I use the plupload API without having to open source my code?
- does the license exclude minified code somehow?

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213767/minified-javascript-and-bsd-license

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102507/can-i-use-a-gnu-licensed-piece-of-javascript-on-a-commercial-website

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Disclaimer: IANAL

Short answers:

- yes, you can use plupload without open sourcing your code
- no, minifying is not excluded by the license

Rationale based on my understanding to the **GNU GPL 2.0 license** is this:

1. as long as your code is not a derivative work of the GPL'ed work, you are fine. In this case, your code does not extend, modify or otherwise depend on [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/index.php) other than using it over well published interfaces, so it can hardly be argued to derive form it. Please note this interpretation is [debated and untested in court](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works) (as per comment by @apsillers).
2. minifying the GPL'ed work is fine, as the minified version is really a binary (executable) version of the source code. This is permitted.
3. you have to offer to provide the GPL'ed code, that is plupload, on request to anyone using your website.

BTW: To be on the safe side, you may want to consider buying one of their [commercial license](http://www.plupload.com/commercial.php). And no, I am not in any way affiliated to plupload.

** Updates

- noted emphasis on GPL 2.0
- added link to further information on derivate work interpretation

Comment: Yeah 15 bucks vs effort, really a no brainer. Shill out the cash and relax :), use the newly gained time to develop more

Comment: +1. You second and third points are quite correct. However, your first point (while very well-reasoned) is *slightly* dubious from a practical legal standpoint. Whether GPL linking creates a derivative work has remained untested in court and is a [highly-opinionated question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_General_Public_License#Linking_and_derived_works). Still, good answer.

Comment: Point 1 in this answer is much too definite. Lawyers don't agree about this, and it hasn't been tested in court. For example the Free Software Foundation, who *wrote* the GPL license, take the opposite view.

Comment: Yeah, giving some OSS developers a round isn't going to kill me, sure. Still interesting to figure this out though. I'm still curious wether minifying all libs into a single ..min.js would have different implications than just minifying one lib. I guess nobody is ever going to waste money on court to find out :)

Comment: I use a simple self directed question: Will my program work without the GPL artifact. If not then I cannot use the GPL'ed product. Think of cat and grep. Cat works perfectly without grep. However, openssh cannot function with openssl.

Comment: The fact they have a commercial license option should mean something. Theoretically you should not be able to use their GPL v2 code in your closed source system. These types of questions come up time and time again and people attempt to rationalize using GPL code in their closed source system. Buy the license.

Comment: Agree with "buy the license, support your developers," in general. However, where the rubber really meets the road here is if I want to use this in a CMS--which I do. And in fact I want to host this software myself on lots of domains/subdomains. Oh, did I mention I'm doing this for free? But I don't want to open-source my code, or (more generally applicable) maybe I want to use the BSD or MIT license...things just got a lot more complicated, or expensive. I can't buy a license for every site that I'm hosting for free. And it's not clear if I can use the GPLv2 software at all in closed-source.

Comment: @S'pht'Kr your cause is well understood - still even if you do your work for free and see it a valuable service to the community, this doesn't mean you automatically get the full rights to do whatever with GPL'd software (as with any license, for that matter). It's quite simple really, if you can play by the GPL's rule, great. If you can't or don't want to, don't use the software.

Comment: @miraculixx You misconstrued my comment as ends justifying the means, which it wasn't--the core question is still the relevant one (which you don't attempt to address), my comment was more in response to Andrew Finnell's (also) oversimplistic response. I would buy the license if it was economically viable, since it's not, I'm trying to understand the application the license to my situation...which neither of you helped.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you may use GPL licensed javascript on a commercial page. You simply have to meet the distribution requirements. The license does not exclude using minified code, but you will have to make the non-minified version available as well. The easiest way to do this would be to include a comment with a link to the non-minified sources hosted on your site at the top of the minified code.

If you modify the GPL code in any way, your modifications will have to be GPL as well, so they should be included in the non-minified sources that you provide.

Comment: Free software foundation and GPL does not want their products used in commercial software for profit. Its in their motto. And if that is not enough, watch the movie Open Source and listen about the philosophy from the creators mouth directly.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell that is completely wrong and misses the whole point of the free and open source software movements. The creators are happy for their products to be used in commercial software for profit, as long as the software remains open-source. This does prevent some business models for monetizing the software (selling shrink-wrap licenses becomes much less effective), but it absolutely does not prevent all commercial use.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell "Commercial" and "respecting the [four freedoms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_Freedoms_(Free_software))" are hardly mutually exclusive. You mention the FSF motto -- isn't the latter half of Stallman's motto "[*not* free as in free beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gratis_versus_libre#.22Free_beer.22_vs_.22free_speech.22_distinction)"? How did you come to believe the motto says the *exact opposite* of what it does? Or are we thinking of different mottoes?

Comment: The motto is free as in freedom. But you are missing an important distinction. The freedoms are to protect others. It's copy-left. You cannot use GPL products in a closed-source system. This is why products like MySQL have a commercial license and a GPL license. Even in his interviews he suggests that companies profit by creating support services around the GPL products. The products remain open and usable but can never be closed. The GPL license is viral despite what apologists say. In the end the only thing that matters if the judge during the court case.

Comment: @apsillers It is extremely ironic that one of his mottos is Free as in Freedom. But it is not completely Free in that regards. If it was, one could take the code, make modifications and close source it for internal use. But you cannot do that. There are restrictions. Hence, it is not Free. The Freedoms are there to protect the other people in the community and to ensure they always have access to the code. But rarely anything is purely Free such as Anarchy. This is exactly why FSS and Open Source are two different movements.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell The motto is "Free as in freedom, not free as in free beer", to acknowledge the distinction between *libre* and *gratis* and demonstrate that FSF-approved free software can also be commercial. To say that the FSF "does not want their products used in commercial software" is patently false. You are conflating "proprietary" with "commercial" -- [you can make money with free software](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/selling.html) without resorting to a dual proprietary license.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Furthermore, it is a philosophical truism to say that there can be no perfect freedom. Every freedom granted must naturally impose some corresponding restriction. The FSF has selected what freedoms are most important to them, as enumerated in the [four freedoms](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html), and enacted the necessary restrictions to ensure that those freedoms are maintained in their software. In that regard, yes, it is not perfectly free (since there is no such thing) -- it adheres to a well-specified definition of freedom.

Comment: It doesn't change the fact you cannot use GPL code in a closed source system. I don't see many Apache license lawyers but we have a GPL lawyer ourselves. Yes you are correct I should of said proprietary not commercial. I see very few examples of the commercial GPL though where the "product" isn't support.

Comment: @AndrewFinnell Absolutely, I agree with you 100% on that.